# Iterate through 2 Java NodeList elements

Tags: java, xml, dom

I know this is simpler than what it seems but I cannot figure it out...

How can I iterate through two Java NodeList collections to see if there is a match.

EG:

```
NodeList NODE1 = doc1.getElementsByTagName("tag1");

NodeList NODE2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("tag2");
```

I want to iterate through `NODE1` and `NODE2` to see if there is any matching data in the 2 tags. I have Java foundation knowledge and I'm new to the XML side of things so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried converting to strings and using an if statement, check to see if there is any matching values. I think my main problem is trying to work out the proper structure of the for-loop to iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something on the lines of this:

```
public Collection<Node> getMatchingNodes(NodeList n1, NodeList n2, Class<? extends Node> typeToMatch){
    Collection<Node> n1Nodes = getNodes(n1, typeToMatch);
    Collection<Node> n2Nodes = getNodes(n2, typeToMatch);
    n1Nodes.retainAll(n2Nodes);
    return n1Nodes;
}

private Collection<Node> getNodes(NodeList nodeList, Class<? extends Node> typeToMatch){
    Collection<Node> n1Nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
        if(nodeList.item(1).getClass() == typeToMatch){
            n1Nodes.add(nodeList.item(i));
        }
    }
    return n1Nodes;
}
```

Note that this only compares Nodes of the same type e.g. Text.